# What is novel consensus algorithm

Tags: hyperledger, bitcoin

I found the following information in the Hyperldeger sawtooth white paper.

> a novel consensus mechanism known as proof-of-work which allows for
>   permissionless and anonymous participation in the consensus protocol

That means that novel consensus algorithm is equal to PoW?
What is the definition of the novel consensus algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the word `novel` here is used as an adjective.
Which means `new` or `unusual` consensus algorithm in this context.
A `novel consensus algorithm` is not a thing.